# How to change laravel Default pagination slider range from 13 to 5

Tags: laravel-4, pagination

I searched everywhere for how to change the number of pages after which laravel change the pagination from listing all pages to using a pagination slider. the default number is 13 but how can i change that to lets say 5 or 7 ?

Answer (score 0):

The default of 13 is hardcoded into Laravel. The comments in the file explain why:

```
// The hard-coded thirteen represents the minimum number of pages we need to
// be able to create a sliding page window. If we have less than that, we
// will just render a simple range of page links insteadof the sliding.
```

The way around this is to create your own pagination view and then change `app/config/view/` to point to your custom view as explained in the [Documentation](http://laravel.com/docs/pagination)